# I need help detouring a function that makes a system call using inline asm

Tags: c, assembly, powerpc

I'm attempting to hook a function, but I am having a bit of trouble when I attempt the hook I crash.
What happens is I hook the function, when the function is called I crash at address 0x00000000 with an exception of 0xC0000005(Access violation reading memory at 0x00000000.)

The function I am trying to hook makes a system call and is below.

```
void __declspec(naked) HvxGetVersions(DWORD dwMagic, DWORD dwMode, unsigned addr, QWORD outBuff, DWORD dwLength) {
    __asm {
        li    r0, 0
        sc
        blr
    }
}
```

Here is how I would attempt to hook the function

```
typedef void(* tHvxGetVersions)(DWORD dwMagic, DWORD dwMode, unsigned addr, QWORD outBuff, DWORD dwLength);
tHvxGetVersions HvxGetVersionsOriginal;
void __declspec(naked) HvxGetVersionsHook(DWORD dwMagic, DWORD dwMode, unsigned addr, QWORD outBuff, DWORD dwLength) {
    printf("HvxGetVersions Called\n");

    //I've tried replicating what the function does like this below
    _asm {
        li    r0, 0
        sc
        blr
    }

    //I've also tried doing this(Note I would not do the asm and this just showing you what i've attempted)
    HvxGetVersionsOriginal(dwMagic, dwMode, addr, outBuff, dwLength);
}

//Note I obviously know that I wouldn't be using the address 0x00000000 it's just a placeholder.
HvxGetVersionsOriginal = (tHvxGetVersions)HookFunctionStub(0x00000000, &HvxGetVersionsHook);
```

The functions that I am using above are posted below.

```
void PatchInJump(DWORD* pAddress, DWORD dwDestination, bool bLinked) {
    pAddress[0] = 0x3D600000 + ((dwDestination >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
    if (dwDestination & 0x8000) 
        pAddress[0] += 1;
    pAddress[1] = 0x396B0000 + (dwDestination & 0xFFFF);
    pAddress[2] = 0x7D6903A6;
    pAddress[3] = bLinked ? 0x4E800421 : 0x4E800420;
}

void __declspec(naked) GLPR(void) {
    __asm {
        std     r14, -0x98(sp)
        std     r15, -0x90(sp)
        std     r16, -0x88(sp)
        std     r17, -0x80(sp)
        std     r18, -0x78(sp)
        std     r19, -0x70(sp)
        std     r20, -0x68(sp)
        std     r21, -0x60(sp)
        std     r22, -0x58(sp)
        std     r23, -0x50(sp)
        std     r24, -0x48(sp)
        std     r25, -0x40(sp)
        std     r26, -0x38(sp)
        std     r27, -0x30(sp)
        std     r28, -0x28(sp)
        std     r29, -0x20(sp)
        std     r30, -0x18(sp)
        std     r31, -0x10(sp)
        stw     r12, -0x8(sp)
        blr
    }
}

DWORD RelinkGPLR(DWORD SFSOffset, DWORD* SaveStubAddress, DWORD* OriginalAddress) {
    DWORD Instruction = NULL, Replacing;
    DWORD* Saver = (DWORD*)GLPR;

    if (SFSOffset & 0x2000000) 
        SFSOffset |= 0xFC000000;

    Replacing = OriginalAddress[SFSOffset / 0x04];
    for (DWORD i = NULL; i < 0x14; i++) {
        if (Replacing == Saver[i]) {
            DWORD NewAddress = (DWORD)&Saver[i] - (DWORD)SaveStubAddress;
            Instruction = (0x48000001 | (NewAddress & 0x03FFFFFC));
        }
    } 
    return Instruction;
}

void HookFunctionStart(DWORD* pAddress, DWORD* pSaveStub, DWORD dwDestination) {
    if ((pAddress!= NULL) && (pSaveStub!= NULL)) {
        DWORD dwRelocation = (DWORD)(&pAddress[0x04]);
        pSaveStub[0x00] = (0x3D600000 + ((dwRelocation >> 0x10) & 0xFFFF));
        pSaveStub[0x01] = (0x616B0000 + (dwRelocation & 0xFFFF));
        pSaveStub[0x02] = 0x7D6903A6;

        for (DWORD i = 0; i < 0x04; i++) {
            if ((pAddress[i] & 0x48000003) == 0x48000001) 
                pSaveStub[i + 0x03] = RelinkGPLR((pAddress[i] & ~0x48000003), &pSaveStub[i + 0x03], &pAddress[i]);
            else pSaveStub[i + 0x03] = pAddress[i];
        }

        pSaveStub[0x07] = 0x4E800420;
        __dcbst(NULL, pSaveStub);
        __sync();
        __isync();
        PatchInJump(pAddress, dwDestination, false);
    }
}

char m_hookSection[0x500];
int m_hookCount;
DWORD HookFunctionStub(DWORD dwAddress, void* pFunction) {
    DWORD* startStub = (DWORD*)&m_hookSection[m_hookCount * 32];
    m_hookCount++;

    for (auto i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        startStub[i] = 0x60000000;
    startStub[7] = 0x4E800020;

    HookFunctionStart((DWORD*)dwAddress, startStub, (DWORD)pFunction);
    return (DWORD)startStub;
}
```

Comment: You say you obviously wouldn't be using address 0x0, but just to be sure, you are receiving the same error when using different (valid) addresses?

Comment: Yes, that is just a place holder to post on here, the actual address to the function is 0x90E0DD10

Comment: I don't see `naked` listed as either a [PowerPC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/PowerPC-Function-Attributes.html) or [Common](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) function attribute.  Unsupported feature?  Targets that do support it [say](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Function-Attributes.html) *Only basic asm statements can safely be included in naked functions (see Basic Asm). While using extended asm or a mixture of basic asm and C code may appear to work, they cannot be depended upon to work reliably and are not supported.*  So watch out for that.

Comment: The very first function is the function I'm trying to hook it works perfectly. I could create a test module to use that function and it will work fine, but hooking it is a different story

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Did Jack say which compiler he is using? Maybe he does not use GCC.

Comment: I'm using the right compiler, I can build the source and simply call the very first function in the post and it will work fine and preform how it is supposed to, the only problem is hooking it.

Comment: @JackLeon I believe you that you use the right compiler. I just mentioned that David obviously assumes that you use a certain compiler and says that the compiler manual does not mention certain features. However, there are a lot of (commercial) compilers for the PowerPC, so David cannot know which compiler you are using if you did not write it.

Comment: About your problem: `naked` means that the compiler does not create any code that is **absolutely** required in a function that contains C code. This only makes sense if the function is consisting of 100% assembly code or if you add this required code using inline assembly. If you are putting C statements in a `naked` function, the program will probably crash...

Comment: On the other hand, the system call (`sc` instruction) obviously requires the arguments to be located in certain CPU registers, so the inline assembly code will only work in a `naked` function and only if no other code (e.g. `printf`) is before the inline assembly code. Otherwise, the `printf` would destroy the content of the CPU registers...

Comment: Pretty sure I've gone without the printf before and still crashed, but I'll give it ago and let you know my results